# get value from select list to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a select list and I want to take the value selected and pass it to de controller, How can I do that?

this is my code

```
<select id="SelectImageType" onchange='submit();'>
  <option value="0">Select Image Type</option>
  <%foreach (var type in Model.ImageTypes)
    { %>
      <option value="<%=type.Key%>"><%=type.Name%></option>
  <%} %>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use name  and in your controller use form collection to collect selected values

```
<select id="SelectImageType" onchange='submit();' name ="image">
<option value="0">Select Image Type</option>
<%foreach (var type in Model.ImageTypes)
{ %>
      <option value="<%=type.Key%>"><%=type.Name%></option>
<%} %>
</select>
```

In your controller action

```
     ActionResult YourActionName(FormCollection collection){
         var selectedImages = collection["image"];
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel but I have a error. (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'name' is not a valid attribute of element 'option'. Any idea.

Comment: Sorry, may bad use move name to select, I have modified my code above

Answer (score 0):

The best why to do it is to use a DropDownListFor and then add the result into the model.

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedImageType, new SelectList((IEnumerable)Model.ImageTypes, "Key", "Name"))%>
```

Controller:

```
ActionResult YourActionName(Model model){
     var selectedImages = m.SelectedImageType;
}
```